# How can I remove the handles and cartridges from this Delta faucet?

Tags: bathroom, faucet, leaking

I have a faucet leaking in my bathroom. It’s leaking from the hot water side. The problem is I can’t find a way to take off the handles on the faucet. The handles are all smooth and one piece. There is nothing to pry off. No small set screws in the back.

I think it’s a Delta model but I’m not sure. Any ideas?

[image: leaky faucet][image: second picture of leaky faucet]

Answer (score 2):

I have similar faucets and to access the cartridge unscrew the base counterclockwise. The base and the handle will come off as one unit.

Comment: "Obviously".  :)  I have always wondered how you design something like that, that has to screw down tightly, but also has to align perfectly with the shape of the things around it, without a set screw. It's magic?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Delta Flynn faucet manual](https://media.deltafaucet.com/MandI/88859%20Rev%20C.pdf):

> Remove handles by hand turning handle base counterclockwise.

[image]